# Mongo Shell becomes unresponsive after connecting to AWS Document DB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I created an AWS Document DB in the same region as my EC2. When I try to connect to it using the command provided by AWS the terminal seems to get stuck.

[image]

The ec2 and Document DB are in the same region.
Document DB's security group allows 27017 access.
Both are in the same VPC.

I don't understand why it says connected but then doesn't allow me to enter commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asds_asds
You can check your working process from here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-ec2.html to see if you missed something.